# perform operation only if checkbox checked using output tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I would like to use HTML5 to complete basic math dynamically. This is completely easily via the output tag as shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp

My requirement includes a checkbox that when check will subtract from a. When unchecked, b will not be subtracted from a.

When I uncheck the checkbox the value stays at 1. I understand that when the POST is made the value 1 won't be submitted to the server. Is the only way to change the value to 0 on the client javascript or is there a work around that will allow me to use native HTML5?

I haven't found other example code for the output code that includes using a checkbox's value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The output element</h1>

<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)-(parseInt(b.value)*parseInt(s.value))">
<input type="checkbox" id="s" name="s" checked="checked" value="1">
0
<input type="range" id="a" value="50">100
-<input type="number" id="b" value="50">
=<output name="x" for="a b s"></output>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your checkbox will always have a value of 1, whether or not it is checked.

if it is not checked when submitting the form, then the name and value of this checkbox will not be transmitted

the solution is to check if the checkbox is checked (true) or not (false)

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form');

ComputeSum(); // on load...

myForm.oninput = ComputeSum;
  
function ComputeSum() {
  myForm.o.value= (myForm.s.checked)
                    ? myForm.a.valueAsNumber -myForm.b.valueAsNumber
                    : myForm.a.value
}
```

```css
small { color: grey; }
```

```html
<h1>The output element</h1>

<form action="" id="my-form">
    <input type="checkbox"  name="s" checked   >
  <small>0</small>
  <input type="range" name="a" value="50">
  <small>100</small>
  -
  <input type="number" name="b" value="50">
  =
  <output name="o"></output>
</form>
```